# struts2 Escape Namespace Definition

Tags: java, struts2

In my struts.xml (the package name is `website`) I have an include to a child xml:

```
<include file="child.xml"/>
```

I also have a welcome `action` inside my struts.xml:

```
<action name="welcome">
     <result>welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
```

My child.xml extends struts.xml:

```
<package name="child" namespace="/child" extends="website">
```

What I would like to do next is create an action in my child.xml that redirects to the `welcome` action. So far I have the following in my child.xml, but it does not work:

```
<action name="">
     <result type="redirectAction">welcome</result>
</action>
```

I think the reason why it doesn't work is because it's going to the URL `/child/welcome` by default instead of just `/welcome`. So I need a way to escape this in the `action` definition in child.xml if possible.

Comment: have you tried  <`result type="redirectAction">welcome</result>
<param name="namespace">/</param> </result>`

Comment: Just tried it now. It still attempts to go to `/child/welcome` instead of just `/welcome`

Comment: Did you try it with a valid action name? Is your root namespace named `"/"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedirectAction` result can have 2 specific params defined by Struts2. One of them is `actionName` and another is `namespace`. So then, if you want to redirect inside your package to an action that it's outside the namespace you have to put the following in your `child.xml`:

```
<action name="whatever">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">welcome</param>
        <param name="namespace">/</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

You can see all the documentation related with the result type `redirectAction` [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/redirect-action-result.html). You have a complete example of how to redirect to a different namespace at the bottom of the page.